# Objective-c runtime list all methods of a class including swizzled ones

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-runtime, method-swizzling

I am interested in mostly the swizzled methods.

I've tried this [Is there any way to list all swizzled methods in an iOS app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38488312/is-there-any-way-to-list-all-swizzled-methods-in-an-ios-app)  but the dependency doesn't work.

Is there a brute force way to just enumerate all classes and methods to compare?

Comment: Any particular reason `class_copyMethodList` won't work for your case? You'll have to traverse the superclass hierarchy of course, but that's trivial.