# Find methods that have been swizzled

Tags: objective-c, lldb

If I am debugging a Mach-O binary using lldb, what data structures in memory can I examine to determine if any methods have been swizzled? Any steps I can follow?

Also, is there a way to determine programmatically if any methods have been swizzled?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any way to list all swizzled methods in an iOS app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38488312/is-there-any-way-to-list-all-swizzled-methods-in-an-ios-app)

Comment: Hi, it seems that its meant for iOS simulator. I am looking for code that will run on devices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you mention `lldb` you can set symbolic breakpoints on:

```
b method_exchangeImplementation
b method_setImplementation
b class_replaceMethod
```

When you hit a breakpoint for:
`method_exchangeImplementations(Method _Nonnull m1, Method _Nonnull m2)`
you can inspect the `m1` `m2` args selector names like this:

```
po (SEL)method_getName($arg1)
po (SEL)method_getName($arg2)
```

For `method_setImplementation(Method _Nonnull m, IMP _Nonnull imp)`:

```
po (SEL)method_getName($arg1)
```

For `class_replaceMethod(Class cls, SEL name, IMP imp, const char *types)`

```
po $arg1
po (SEL)method_getName($arg2)
```

Those `Method` will likely be yielded through previous calls to:

```
class_getInstanceMethod(Class _Nullable cls, SEL _Nonnull name)
class_getClassMethod(Class _Nullable cls, SEL _Nonnull name)
```

so after:

```
b class_getInstanceMethod
b class_getClassMethod
```

and hitting respective breakpoints, to inspect class:

```
po $arg1
```

to inspect selector:

```
po (SEL)method_getName($arg2)
```

The best place to setup those symbolic breakpoints would be here:

```
__attribute__((constructor))
static void premain() {
int i = 0;
i++; // put xcode breakpoint here and when hit prep your lldb symbolic bps
}
```